# How to copy pbi object from powerbi D3 plugin?

Tags: json, d3.js, powerbi

Is there anyway to copy JSON content from powerBI tool?

I have some custom chart(via D3.js Plugin) in a pbi file and I am getting the data from some tables. I can see the JSON content in the pbi object(3rd widget after going to edit in ellipsis ...). But I am unable to copy anything from this.

I want this JSON data in a separate file.

[image: PBI Object View]

Comment: I also had the same problem, you can not copy any thing from this object. You can print the current page and then select the text to copy, i found this makeshifter to work with it.

Comment: This is the case of small JSON object but if my data goes beyond the screen size then?. I want some generic solution for this as in some files my data is of more than 1000 lines and can go beyond the height and width.